# Multiple Notifications while repeating them in an interval of one Day.Used Unique ID in notify function but unable to get desired output

Tags: java, android

Problem: All notifications are seen On the day when they are set. But after One Day interval when the time comes for all the notifications to be displayed together then only the notification I set Last is visible (maybe I am wrong that's not the last one but only one notification is displayed)

I have gone through different solutions of Multiple Notification in android through various sites as well as stack overflow. All are mentioning to use a Unique Id in notificationManager.notify() but I have already done this but still same result..

This is my code for generating the notification as well as repeating it with one day interval
I have used shared preferences for unique ID

```
Intent intent=new Intent(PolicyDetails.this,AlarmReciever.class);
            pref=this.getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);
            editor=pref.edit();
            editor.putInt("MID",pref.getInt("MID",0)+1);
            editor.commit();
  PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PolicyDetails.this,pref.getInt("MID",0),intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
          //  Constants.setMID(Constants.MID+1);
            AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)PolicyDetails.this.getSystemService(PolicyDetails.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
```

This is my Notification Builder Code

```
Intent i1=new Intent(context,PaidCancel.class);
    Intent i2=new Intent(context,PaidCancel.class);
    i1.putExtra("code",1);
    i2.putExtra("code",2);
    pref=context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);


    PendingIntent pi =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,i1,0);
    PendingIntent p2=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,1,i2,0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mnotifybuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery)
            .setContentTitle("Alarm fired").setContentText("A Remainder  for your task No "+pref.getInt("MID",0)).setAutoCancel(false).addAction(R.id.paid,"Button1",pi).addAction(R.id.dismiss,"Button2",p2).setVibrate(new long[]{1000,1000,1000,1000});
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)`enter code here`context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);




    notificationManager.notify(pref.getInt("MID",0),mnotifybuilder.build());


Log.d("Increased...","increased"+pref.getInt("MID",0));
```

This is my Paidcancel class code

```
static public class PaidCancel extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getIntExtra("code",0)==1) {
            Log.d("see once...", "paid button clivked");

        }
        else
            if(intent.getIntExtra("code",0)==2)
                Log.d("see once..","cancel Button clicked");
        else
            Log.d("not  ","no");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you really sure that you're using a unique ID for each `Notification`? You're using the same key for each ID you're pulling from `SharedPreferences` - `pref.getInt("MID",0)`. Unless you're changing that preference before each time you call `notify()`, that's going to return the same `int` for each one.

Comment: sorry My Mistake !! I have done it in my actual code but forget to copy paste here (stack overflow)            For Unique ID i have used                                  pref=this.getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);
            editor=pref.edit();
            editor.putInt("MID",pref.getInt("MID",0)+1);
            editor.commit();                        and for knowing it at run time i have used                    Log.d("Increased...","increased"+pref.getInt("MID",0));.......................Now i have edited it here(stack overflow) please Review it

Comment: OK, then I'm a little unclear on the expected behavior. You're setting multiple daily alarms with `Notification`s. These are working for the individual days for which they're set. But then, one day, you want to display all of those separate daily `Notification`s simultaneously? That is, what exactly do you mean by "when the time comes for all the notifications to be displayed together"?

Comment: Yes you are right..acually i am making users to set remainders for their policies ...so for testing i set 5 remainders at time 5:15 so the day on which i set them suppose 21 st of january they all were displayed but then i changed my mobile time and date  then only one notification was displayed ..

Comment: OK, I'm still not exactly sure what you mean, but if you have 5 `Notification`s that are supposed to be showing at the same time, then I would think that your problem is still the ID. The code for the `Notification` is called in `AlarmReciever`, right? But you only increment the ID before you set the alarm. If 5 alarms fire at the same time (approximately), then there's never a chance for the ID to be incremented, because, as mentioned, that only happens when you set the alarms, not when they fire.

Comment: thanks Mike for pointing out the flaw.."But you only increment the ID before you set the alarm. If 5 alarms fire at the same time (approximately), then there's never a chance for the ID to be incremented, because, as mentioned, that only happens when you set the alarms, not when they fire"    So i just put the code of incrementation below the Notification.build()...............and it worked .

Comment: Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

> This code works for me to create unique notification id..

```
SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName()
, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

int notificationNumber = prefs.getInt("notificationNumber", 0);

// generate Notify id from SharedPreferences.
mNotificationManager.notify(notificationNumber, mBuilder.build());


SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
if (notificationNumber < 5000)
                notificationNumber++;
else
                notificationNumber = 0;

editor.putInt("notificationNumber", notificationNumber);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: I dit it that way only...but it still it didnt worked i dont know why